# What is the meaning of below c# code (Chaining the Conditional Ternary Operator)

Tags: c#

```
ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
                : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was added."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was removed."
                : "";
```

Comment: Read ternary operators

Comment: @StuartLC It is off-topic but it is so weird almost all MSDN links add this `f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396` part at the end of url on these days..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The code listed is from the scaffolded `ManageController` in an ASP.Net MVC 5 app)

It is a chained use of the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Although the same result could be achieved with nested if statements:

```
if (message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess)
    ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your password has been changed."
else if (message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess)
    ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your password has been set."
...
```

or a switch statement

```
switch (message)
   case ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess:
      ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your password has been changed.";
      break;
   case ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess:
      ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your password has been set.";
      break;
    ...
```

Using the conditional operator in chained fashion has the benefit of avoiding the repetitive assignment of `ViewBag.StatusMessage`, as it allows projection of a result which must be of the same type, and thus allows a single assignment. It also discourages coding side-effecting behaviour which is possible in an `if` or `switch` statement.

**Edit, other alternatives**

If the number of permutations becomes very large, I would opt for a `Dictionary` lookup pattern to map the `ManageMessageId` values to strings to set in the ManageController's `Viewbag`, as this will reduce the number of comparisons in order to match the appropriate key:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<ManageMessageId, string> _messageDictionary 
= new Dictionary<ManageMessageId, string>
  {
      {ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess, "Your password has been changed."},
      {ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess, "Your password has been set."},
      // ...
  };
```

The equivalent mapping code would then be simply (with just a single use of the conditional operator) - `ManageMessageId` is an enum:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
{
   ViewBag.StatusMessage = (message.HasValue)
      ? _messageDictionary[message.Value]
      : "";
```

Comment: I have used my previous code only and it's very interesting too after getting the meaning of this.
But I have tried StuartLC code as well getting same behaviour only.
Thanks StuartLC.